# SQL -Listing between Two dates for each record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My data source looks like below.

[image]

And I want output like below.

Basically, it should list each Employee multiple times for each date between those periods.

[image]

For quick and easy, below is the Temp Data code.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Emp

CREATE TABLE #Emp
(
    EmpID VARCHAR(6), 
    StartDate DATE, 
    EndDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO #Emp 
VALUES ('E001','2021-08-01', '2021-08-05'),
       ('E002','2021-08-22', '2021-08-22'),
       ('E003','2021-08-15', '2021-08-17')
```

Comment: @Dale,  I agree with avoiding images, but posting "What I tried" is not always necessary and possible. When the questioner is blind and does not have any logic or hope, there is no point to post silly things under "What I tried". Images sometimes also give easy and quick understanding to persons who are attending  questions. Yes, the drawback is, they consume resources on StackOverflow servers which is not good for servers.

Comment: Further reasons [not to use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a calendar table and join that.

```
Select e.EmpId, c.Date
from #Emp e
join Calendar c
  on c.Date between e.StartDate and e.EndDate
```

Answer (score 3):

Here I have used recursive cte. If there is a chance to have more than 100 days between two dates then you need to explicitly mention the level of recursion at the end. For 300 days it will be `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 300)`
Highest permissible value for MAXRECURSION is 32767. If you mention `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)` then it will take the highest value.

I have added a new answer which doesn't involve recursion but a simple cross apply. I would prefer this solution but it's only good for date ranges within 2048 days. You can also create a table with number sequence to overcome this.

```
 CREATE TABLE #Emp
 (
     EmpID VARCHAR(6), 
     StartDate DATE, 
     EndDate DATE
 )
 
 INSERT INTO #Emp 
 VALUES ('E001','2021-08-01', '2021-08-05'),
        ('E002','2021-08-22', '2021-08-22'),
        ('E003','2021-08-15', '2021-08-17')
```

Query:

```
 with dates as 
 (
     select EmpId, StartDate newdate from #Emp
     Union ALL
     select dates.EmpId, DATEADD(day, 1, newdate)
     from dates inner join #Emp e on dates.EmpId=e.EmpId
     where newdate < enddate
 )
 select EmpId,newdate [date]
 from dates order by empid,newdate
```

Output with recursion:

| EmpId | date |
| --- | --- |
| E001 | 2021-08-01 |
| E001 | 2021-08-02 |
| E001 | 2021-08-03 |
| E001 | 2021-08-04 |
| E001 | 2021-08-05 |
| E002 | 2021-08-22 |
| E003 | 2021-08-15 |
| E003 | 2021-08-16 |
| E003 | 2021-08-17 |

Query without recursion:

```
 select EmpId,newdate [date] from #Emp
 cross apply(
 SELECT DISTINCT dateadd(day,number,startdate) newdate
 FROM master..[spt_values] 
 WHERE number BETWEEN 0 and datediff(day,startdate,enddate) )as d
```

Output:

| EmpId | date |
| --- | --- |
| E001 | 2021-08-01 |
| E001 | 2021-08-02 |
| E001 | 2021-08-03 |
| E001 | 2021-08-04 |
| E001 | 2021-08-05 |
| E002 | 2021-08-22 |
| E003 | 2021-08-15 |
| E003 | 2021-08-16 |
| E003 | 2021-08-17 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3b22db1ac9be5489c1d1304be01a510d)*

Answer (score 0):

If your database doesn't have a built-in calendar table, you can use any of the built-in system tables or any random table (which has sufficient rows) from which you can generate numbers ranging from 1 to n, and use it in the below fashion. I have used a built-in table called `columns` from sql_server:

```sql
select      t1.id, 
            dateadd(day, t2.n-1, t1.start_date)
from 
(
  select    id, 
            start_date, 
            datediff(day, start_date, end_date) dur 
  from      t1
)           t1,
( 
  select    row_number() 
  over      (order by object_id) n 
  from      sys.columns 
)           t2
where       (t2.n-1) <= t1.dur
```